# How to add alpha filter to any HTML element and keep the other filters in IE?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

If I have this HTML

```
<img src="aaa.png" id="a" style="filter: alpha(opacity=100)"/>
```

Then this javascript works in IE6

```
document.getElementById("a").filters.alpha.opacity = 60;
```

But if no style is set

```
<img src="aaa.png" id="a" style=""/>
```

The javascript throws an error *'filters.alpha' is null or not an object*

This code works

```
document.getElementById("a").style.filter = "alpha(opacity=60)";
```

But then the other filters applied to the image are overwritten. So the question is: *How to add alpha filter to any HTML element and keep the other filters in IE?*

**edit** I would like pure javascript (not jQuery) solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems to me you can only add new elements through the `style.filter` property, with `filters` you can only manipulate already existing ones.

`filter` is a collection object, you can find the docs here: [filters Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It gives you a nice and easy way to play with your **existing** filters, you can turn them on and off (`enabled`), etc.

For example, you can use

```
obj.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha").opacity=20;
```

or (if alpha was you first filter declaration)

```
obj.filters.item(0).opacity=20;
```

**CLASSES**

Most of the time you're better off storing your filter declarations under certain classes in your CSS, and only using JS to assign the right classes instead of manipulating `style` values directly.

Comment: No. The code you suggest throws an exception if Alpha filter was not set and nothing happens (at least in my IE6 tests). You may use style.filter+=... - but in this case the strings grows more and more.

Comment: Oh misunderstood... I just gave a nice way to access the current filters, but I also emphasized that with filters you cannot add new ones.

Comment: Yes. At least I came to the same conclusion from the same MSDN source at the same time :-) It helped me to create a bulletproof(?) function (see my post here). With the enabled property, it is possible to create / modify / unset any filter in any IE. So solved, answer accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

After some more testing, I come with this solution

```
var filter = function(obj,f,params) {
  var found, nf, dx = "DXImageTransform.Microsoft.";

  // check if DXImageTransform.Microsoft.[Filter] or [Filter] filter is set
  try { nf = obj.filters.item(dx+f); found = true; } catch(e) {}
  if(!found) try { nf = obj.filters.item(f); found = true; } catch(e) {}

  // filter is set - change existing one
  if(found) {
    nf.Enabled = true; // if exists, it might be disabled
    if(params) for(var i in params) nf[i] = params[i];
  }

  // filter is not set - apply new one
  else {
    nf = "";
    if(params) for(var i in params) nf+= i.toLowerCase()+"="+params[i]+",";
    if(params) nf = "("+nf.substr(0,nf.length-1)+")";
    obj.style.filter+= "progid:"+dx+f+nf+" ";
  }

  // hasLayout property hack
  if(!obj.style.zoom) obj.style.zoom = 1;
};
```

**Example**

```
var obj = document.getElementById("a");
if(document.body.filters) filter(obj,"Alpha",{Opacity:50});
```

I hope this works, if anybody finds a problem, please tell me.

**Sources**

obj.filters property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537452(VS.85).aspx

filter.Alpha http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532967(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Nice coding rules. I almost thought your code sample is obfuscated!

Answer (score 2):

You can give n number of filters you want but just keep appending them one after the other separated by a space. For example ,

```
STYLE="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MotionBlur(strength=50)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60);"
```

Check this link for more : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Yes, this is useful. But how to add filters by javascript?