# Javascript -Change opacity of image depending on result of function

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

So I'm building a game in which you have to choose the right image depending on a random number that is displayed. I'm trying to find a way to change the opacity of the image you click on if you don't pick the right one. I saw many posts about changing opacity onclick or on hover, but I would like to change it only if the image does not correspond to the number. I tried to change codes given in different posts but without success. Maybe I should use an if/else statement? Or a function to change the CSS? This is pretty new for me so I'm a little lost.

```
<body>
<div id="consigne"></div>
<div id="container">

  <input class="img" type="image" id="leve-couche" src="soleil.png" alt="leve-couche-soleil">
  <input class="img" type="image" id="jour" src="jour.png" alt="jour">
  <br />
  <input class="img" type="image" id="nuit" src="nuit.png" alt="nuit">
 </div>

</div>

<script>

var sunrise_sunset = [19, 20 ,6, 7];
var night = [21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var day = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
var hours = sunrise_sunset.concat(night).concat(day);
var consigne = 'Il est ';

var randomHour = Math.floor(Math.random() * hours.length);

document.getElementById("consigne").innerHTML = consigne + '<strong>' + getHourStringValue(randomHour) + '</strong>.';

document.getElementById("leve-couche").addEventListener("click", function(){checkAnswer(sunrise_sunset)}, false);
document.getElementById("nuit").addEventListener("click", function(){checkAnswer(night)}, false);
document.getElementById("jour").addEventListener("click", function(){checkAnswer(day)}, false);

function getHourStringValue(hour) {
  if(hour == 0) { return 'minuit'; }
  if(hour == 12) { return 'midi'; }
  if(hour == 1) { return hour + ' heure'; }
  return hour + ' heures';
}

function checkAnswer(array) {  
  var isCorrect = false;
  for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] == randomHour){
        isCorrect = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if(isCorrect){
    alert('Yeah!');
  }else{
    alert('Try again!');
  }
}

</script>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: This link may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235227/how-to-decrease-css-opacity

Comment: I think OP is asking how to capture the event

Comment: I think he is capturing it properly. Here is really simple jsfiddle of OP code with opacity change: https://jsfiddle.net/3bgd4jax/
Rest is a matter of algorythm - OP may use some key-value map and check if id of an image corresponds to proper value. If yes - change opacity and so on. Similar to fizz-buzz, which every one should be able to code on their own at midnight ;)

C.L. - care about proper html markup more! Errors and warning in such simple code are not what you want to make you problems!

Comment: Thank you ignacy130! It works! Do you know where I can find a good tutorial or a good explanation about key-value map? I've never done it so I'm happy to learn, but I don't want to be even more lost... Anyway thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.opacity="0.5"
```

where you can replace 0.5 with a value between 0 and 1 (the closer to 0 the more transparent it is) and test with the id of one of your images - i.e. "jour" or "nuit".

I have an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/motoyL7u/4/

That shows Javascript that changes the opacity of the two images that do not correspond to the number.

Comment: I couldn't make it work :/ It doesn't change anything on my images.