# How to add filter: alpha using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to add filter: alpha using javascript ?

for opacity i use this code. It's work good.

```
<div id="5">test</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("5").style.opacity = "0.5";
</script>
```

And i tried to use with `filter: alpha` like this but not work, how can i do that ?

for me

```
<div id="5">test</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("5").style.filter = "alpha(opacity=30)";
</script>
```

but not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add alpha filter to any HTML element and keep the other filters in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259824/how-to-add-alpha-filter-to-any-html-element-and-keep-the-other-filters-in-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use CSS.

```
document.getElementById("5").setAttribute("style","opacity:0.3; -moz-opacity:0.3; filter:alpha(opacity=30)");
```

It works on FireFox, Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go:**

```
var element = document.getElementById('5');
element.style.opacity = "0.3";
element.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=30)';
```