# What is the correct syntax of the following angularjs code to change bottom border color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to use something like this:

```
//works fine
angular.element("#startDiscussion")[0].style.border = "1px solid blue";
```

The above works fine. How do I change only the bottom? `border.bottom` does not work, if I use in the above code.

Also need to make a grey filter work for images. Something like the following?

```
angular.element("#yellowUnderReview")[0].style.filter.grayscale = "100%";
```

which should give the result like the following:

```
img {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Is there any documentation available for these?

Comment: Use ng-style instead of what you are doing

Comment: @Weedoze I have a very complicated structure for the css, that's why was trying to avoid ngStyle from beginning.

Comment: Then use `ng-class`

Comment: Yes, `ng-class` is way better than adding styles like this

Comment: Even if you have a very complicated structure you will have one line per property... Thus you will have a lot of `angular.element(...)...`. Use the available directive like `ng-style` or `ng-class`

Comment: @Weedoze Yeah, that's what I am thinking at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `borderBottom` for `border-bottom`.

```
angular.element("#startDiscussion")[0].style.borderBottom = "1px solid blue";
```

For, `filter`, you can use the following:

```
// Standard syntax
angular.element("#yellowUnderReview")[0].style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";

// Code for Safari 6.0 - 9.0
angular.element("#yellowUnderReview")[0].style.WebkitFilter = "grayscale(100%)";
```

Comment: That's perfect. Where did you get the correct syntax? Do you have any link for the same?

Comment: I could not find a concrete article. But the javascript `Object.style` properties for their corresponding css properties could be found easily on google. For a little bit of reference check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use css:

```
#startDiscussion {
    border-bottom: 1px solid pink;
}
```

If you can't use css try to use camel case style, this is the javascript way:

```
borderBottom: 1px solid blue;
```

Check this post also: [How to add alpha filter to any HTML element and keep the other filters in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259824/how-to-add-alpha-filter-to-any-html-element-and-keep-the-other-filters-in-ie)